# In a Case statements Else criteria can I tell it I want to see the value if its 'Y' OR NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a multi-level feedback to some parameters I have. I don't get the NULL values that I want. I am wondering how I do a multi part ELSE statement where I can say ELSE send 'N' or NULL. Here is a abbreviated sample of my code. I know it works without the OR part but without the OR I don't get values that have NULL. I know that its messy data and the business SHOULD always have a Y or N populated but we all know that's not the case.

```
DECLARE @par1 char(1)
DECLARE @par2 char(1)
DECLARE @par3 char(1) 
DECLARE @needs char(1)

SET @needs = 'C'
SET @par1 = CASE @needs WHEN 'C' THEN 'Y' ELSE @par1 = 'N' or @par1 IS NULL END
SET @par2 = CASE @needs WHEN 'S' THEN 'Y' ELSE @par2 = 'N' or @par2 IS NULL END
SET @par1 = CASE @needs WHEN 'L' THEN 'Y' ELSE @par3 = 'N' or @par3 IS NULL END
```

Comment: What is the logic behind these three `CASE` expressions?

Comment: It that case statement of your, just make ELSE NULL and it will return null.

Comment: Why do you want to send `'N'` or `NULL`? Why not just `'N'`? or just `NULL`?

Comment: Good questions. The data is new and some values for the 'N's are also NULL. I want to assume 'N' is NULL. Meaning I don't want my CASE statement to exclude NULLs. The way I have it it ONLY pulls rows of data where the two "other" variables are N. I want to say if you tell me you want Par1 of Y give me Par2s and Par3s if they are 'N' OR Null.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want:

```
SET @par1 = (CASE @needs WHEN 'C' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END)
```

When `@needs` is `NULL`, this will set the value to `'N'`.

If you want a `NULL` value returned as well, you would use a multi-part `CASE`:

```
SET @par1 = (CASE WHEN @needs = 'C' THEN 'Y'
                  WHEN @needs IS NOT NULL THEN 'N'
             END)  --`NULL` is the default.
```

`CASE` is a *scalar* expression.  It returns one value.  Although you can set a variable in MySQL, there is no need to do that for your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`CASE COALESCE(@needs,'NULL') ...` 
to cast the @needs value to a nun-null one (i.e. 'NULL' string) such:

```
SET @par1 = CASE COALESCE(@needs, 'NULL') WHEN 'C' THEN 'Y' WHEN 'NULL' THEN NULL ELSE 'N' END
```

Alternately, you can use the more SQL-standard approach of the `CASE` statement:

```
SET @par1 = CASE 
    WHEN @needs IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN @needs='C' THEN 'Y' 
    ELSE 'N' 
END
```

Comment: You don't need to separately check for `NULL`, you could just bucket `NULL` into the `ELSE` condition.

Comment: I thought he wanted to assign a special meaning to only 'N' and NULL, not for 'Q' for instance... it's very hard to tell from the question what the intent really is.

Comment: I agree with the "very hard" part :-)

Comment: For instance he does have on the 3rd line `CASE @needs WHEN 'L'` - so `@needs` can have at least 'C' and 'L' values, I figured... and probably NULL... so, maybe he can make something of either COALESCE which he can then use as a `WHEN` option or the 3-way branch :)

Comment: I think I figured it out, check the updated answer... if I'm right I will be amazed :))

Comment: Its not that the @needs is null...the value that I want to return in the ELSE statement might be 'N' or NULL. I need both from the ELSE

Comment: @Glock You can not return 'N' OR NULL, we don't have quantum computing (yet). Variables only have one and exactly one value at any given point in time, for the past 70 years or so... so why do you _think_ you need ('N' OR NULL) returned there? Describe what you are trying to achieve, because how you try to achieve it is completely wrong.

Comment: I will be the first to admit that I might not be doing it right. Sorry if I haven't included the full story. I need an SSRS user to have one parameter to chose. They want Par1, Par2 or Par3 in that dropdown. The values of each of those are Y or N. They only want to see rows if ONE of them is Y. So methodically if the first is Y then great stop, otherwise check the next. So I know its not that complicated. I just need a way to run through a Y/N parameter check on three variables. I tried it in my where clause and it blows up.

Comment: If I get Y for the first variable I want to see rows for other data where the other two variables are N OR null. I essentially want to pretend like my NULLs ARE Ns.

Comment: Since you mention rows, I assume you must also have a table somewhere. Would you expand on that? what does it mean "data where the other variables are"? Are you trying to compare a table column to a pre-set variable? Don't be mysterious about it.

Comment: My preset variable is what I get from SSRS....a dropdown of my creation. So if they pick C then I want C to tell my query to: Set Par1 to Y, Par2 to N, Par3 to N...but I ALSO want Par2 and Par3 to return where their values are NULL as well. I know that this would all work if every record had Y or N for Par1, Par 2 and Par3...but my data doesn't. Ns are equal to NULLs.

Comment: Please describe the relation between these variables and the implied table that holds the records... there really is no such thing as a variable that is both NULL and NOT NULL at the same time.

Comment: Fair. I have master student table. I have 2 students Student 1 needs a tudor and his flag is set to Y. The student also needs a mentor and that flag is set to Y. Second student also needs a tudor so their flag is set to Y. But they do not need a mentor but as it should be their flag is not set to N...its set to NULL in the DB. If I run my SP for students that need a tudor...I want both records when I say I don't want records that have a mentor flag set to N....because the mentor flag in this situation is both set to N AND null

Comment: So somewhere you must have something like a query that looks like `SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE ...` ?